# Undo click(function() {return false;})

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, click

I have a question/problem. At some point I need that every element are non-clickable except one div and I have:

```
$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').click(function() {return false;});
```

In the MainDiv i have several other elements (a, img,...) and I need those elements retun to be clickable. It is possible to undo that function or do I need to set every a.href and img.click of those elements again?

Comment: Why not just omit them from the selector in the first place?

Comment: It is impossible to do this without mucking around in undocumented jQuery internals. If you don't mind doing this (and risking your script breaking by a future jQuery update) then it is possible although not very cheap.

Comment: In the first place I need them non-clickable. just when I press a button make them clickable again. Sorry if I didn't understand your reply MДΓΓ БДLL

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').unbind("click");`
Then when you need to reasign the the click functions, just make sure what each click does is wrapped in its on function so you can simply do something like `$(".someEle").click(function(e){ yourCustomeFuncForThisItem(var1, var2); });`

Comment: So Spyk3hh, if I understand what you said... I need to set every elements functions again... is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for event delegation. #MainDiv probably has dozens or hundreds of elements? Just attach one click event handler there, let the event bubble to #MainDiv and see if the thing that was clicked is #Div.

```
$("#MainDiv").click(function(event){
    if ( event.target.id === "Div" ) {
      // do the thing with Div
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').bind('click', false);

$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').unbind('click', false);
```

`$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').bind('click', false);` should be equivalent to `$('#MainDiv *:not(#Div)').click(function() { return false; });`